# Google Places API returns full state name on desktop, abbreviated state on laptop

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps

I have a project using google places and autocomplete. The full city and state name are required by subsequent different APIs on the project.

On desktop and mobile autocomplete shows e.g. `Boise Idaho, USA`, on laptop however autocomplete shows `Boise ID, USA`. I have tested this on several laptop, and each laptop seems to behave the same. I need for any device to show the full state length for all APIs to work correctly.

JS Code:

```
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
};
var input = document.getElementById('cityInput');
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

and on the HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=****&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: not sure why downvoted, the post shows desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself

Comment: Check requests in network tab of browsers. Try to figure out if there are differences in headers of requests. For example, region or language parameter are different on laptop and desktop. Try to force language when you load maps JavaScript API.